# Plone: custom workflows and dynamic local roles

Tags: permissions, workflow, plone

I have a custom Dexterity type that allows a user to specify access restrictions, which are stored as fields on the type. I've created a custom `borg.localrole` `ILocalRoleProvider` which adapts the custom type and returns a set of roles based on those fields. I tested this with the custom type bound to `simple_publication_workflow` and the adapter worked as expected.

However, I need to customise the workflow quite substantially. Once I'd created a new workflow and assigned it to the custom type, the adapter stopped working. Placing a `pdb` breakpoint inside the adapter's initialiser showed it wasn't being called at all. If I change the workflow back to `simple_publication_workflow` it works again as expected, but if set to other standard workflows - such as `one_state_workflow` or `plone_workflow` - the adapter again isn't called.

What am I missing here? How can I have a workflow that interacts with an `ILocalRoleProvider` as expected?

Comment: Not going to answer this yet, because it involves some conjecture, but the local role manager plugin in borg.localrole.workgroup memoizes -- you might need to consider restarting your zope instances after changing your workflow definitions (to blast out cached values), and try again.  You cannot, should not expect the adapter to be instantiated every time by the local role manager plugin (the checkLocalRolesAllowed method is called with an object, the user, and a set of roles -- unlike some of the other methods, it is memoized).

Comment: I've tried restarting the instance after changing the assigned workflow but no success. I have the same problem on a clean build of the site as well, before anything has had a chance to be cached. Thanks for the heads up on `checkLocalRolesAllowed` too, that could cause me some problems in what I'm hoping to achieve here.